# Why is matplotlib failing on import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, importerror

I installed matplotlib using `conda`:

```
conda install matplotlib
```

The following code failed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

With this error message:

> "ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'"

I tried installing matplotlib with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

I got the same error.

I tried loading matplotlib with ubuntu application load and got the same error.

I tried cloning from GitHub with:

```
git clone git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
```

I got the same error.

I looked at the matplotlib directory and did not see a pyplot.py entry.  I did find pyplot.py in matplotlib/lib/matplotlib.  I copied it to matplotlib.  The error went away, but I got another module that pyplot was trying to include.  I found it in matplotlib/lib/matplotlib.  I copied it to matplotlib.  Got another error for another module.  Copied it.  Eventually I got an error for a module I could not find.

I do not know what to try next.

Answer (score 1):

Normally `conda` isn't added to your path (it asks you during the installation if it should do that but the default is "no"), so the default `python` will be the systems Python 2 (you start Python 3 with `python3`).

You could verify this by using:

```
$ which python
```

That will return the path associated with the `python` command. Likely this will return the path to the systems Python 2 "installation".

For example on my Ubuntu machine the commands `which python` and `which python3` return:

```
usr/bin/python   (starts Python 2.7.12)
usr/bin/python3  (starts Python 3.5.2)
```

While my conda installation is somewhere in the `/home/michael/miniconda` directory.

There are several options how you could use the `conda` Python:

- Temporarily add the conda directory it to the PATH. (See for example [How to add [...] to path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402353/how-to-add-home-username-bin-to-path))
- Permanently add the conda directory to the PATH. (see for example [How to add a directory to the path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path))
- Use the `anaconda promt` which gives you a terminal with the conda directory prepended to the PATH.